# Problemas servidor eclipse "Failed to connect to remote VM"

Tags: eclipse

Estimados, estoy intentando reiniciar el servidor desde eclipse y al momento de reiniciarlo en modo debug arroja el siguiente mensaje:

> Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
>   Connection refused: connect

Estimados fialmente para solucionar el inconveniente de forma rápida por honor al tiempo el proceso fue.

1. Finalizar procesos del eclipse.
2. Finalizar procesos de JAVA.
3. Levantar nuevamente el ambiente de desarrollo.

Espero que alguien pueda comentar el motivo por el cual se da este inconveniente.

A modo de comentario me explicaron que ciertos hilos de procesos en el servidor no terminaron correctamente y quedaron tomados. Espero recibir mayor información por alguien que cuente con más conocimientos. 
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué servidor de desarrollo usas? ¿Cómo lo has configurado para habilitar el debug?

Comment: servidor weblogic, para configurar en modo debug? me imagino que te refieres a que el servidor muestre en su log, debes configurar el log4j en modo debug

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer debug en Weblogic hay que modificar el script de arranque,`startWebLogic.cmd`, y añadir:

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n
```

¿Has realizado ese paso?